# Use lsyncd to sync MULTIPLE directories

Tags: linux, bash, lua, rsync

I am using lsyncd to sync one directory, here is my /etc/lsyncd/lsyncd.conf.lua:

```
sync
 {
     default.rsyncssh,
     source="/home/user/sync/",
     host="redacted",
     targetdir="/home/user/sync"
 }
```

I tried adding two sync block but only the first one is working.
How do I do ?

Regards,

Comment: I want to include some directory from `/home/user/sync/` and exclude rest of all directories. Have any idea?

Answer (score 5):

So there are two solutions:

```
targetlist = {

 "server1:/var/www/wiki/", 

 "server2:/var/www/wiki/"

}


for _, server in ipairs( targetlist ) do

sync{ default.rsync,

source="/var/www/wiki/",

target=server

}

end
```

OR
I tried to chain two source= and targetdir =

Example

```
sync
{
        default.rsyncssh,
        source="/home/redacted/sync/",
        host="debian",
        targetdir="/home/user/sync",
        source="/home/pi/sync2/",
        targetdir="/home/user/sync2"

}
```

Here we go

Comment: I have already for loop for multiple remote servers. Then how can I add for loop for the directory?

Comment: you can now add several sync blocks, see https://axkibe.github.io/lsyncd/faq/multiple-targets/